# What is the complexity of the below program?

Tags: c++, c

What is the complexity of the below program? I think it must be O(n), since there is a for loop that runs for n times.

It is a program to reverse the bits in a given integer.

```
unsigned int reverseBits(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int NO_OF_BITS = sizeof(num) * 8;
    unsigned int reverse_num = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_BITS; i++)
    {
        if((num & (1 << i)))
           reverse_num |= 1 << ((NO_OF_BITS - 1) - i);
    }
    return reverse_num;
}
```

What is the complexity of the above program and how? Someone said that the actual complexity is O(log n), but I can't see why.

Comment: Why do you think true complexity should be O(log n)?

Comment: @sharptooth ya. the real complexity of this program is O(log n) how?

Comment: Instead of the magic constant `8`, `#include <limits.h>` and use `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: @learnfromothers - yes, you should. Both time and space complexity is O(1) here.

Comment: @paxdiablo how time complexity is O(1). can u get it me clearly??

Comment: learnfromothers, `sizeof(num)` does not depend on `num` at all, just on the number of bytes (C bytes, not necessarily 8-bit bytes) in an `unsigned int`. Hence `sizeof(num) * 8` is a constant. See the answer from @Benoit.

Comment: @paxdiablo ya thanks....do u have any good materials r site to study the algorithm and their complexity calculation.....

Comment: @learnfromothers, you have actually accepted an answer that is _wrong!_ If you must learn from others, at least learn the right things :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The algorithm is still O(n), since O-notation describes the asymptotic complexity for very large inputs. This particular implementation places a fixed bound on the input size (and therefore a corresponding bound on the running time for any allowed input), but that doesn't change the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: To which I would simply answer, the question was: What is the complexity of the below _program?_ :-) Saying that program is O(n) is incorrect, even if the algorithm was, for different integer sizes.

Comment: @paxdiablo: saying it's O(1) is also incorrect, unless you redefine O-notation to mean something other than asymptotic complexity. This particular implementation has constant running time; the algorithm has asymptotic complexity of O(n).

Comment: He's asking for the complexity of the program, not the algorithm in general, which does mean the implementation! The complexity of this implementation is without a doubt O(1), but as for the general algorithm, it's O(n).

Comment: @MisterSir: As I've said a few times now, O-notation expresses the asymptotic complexity as the input size grows. It cannot be used to express the running time of an implementation with a fixed input size. This implementation may have a fixed running time for a given size of `unsigned int`, but it is *not* O(1), unless you have redefined O to mean something other than its usual meaning.

Comment: @Mike This specific implementation is O(1)! No matter what, the algorithm will do the same(in this implementation). Of course the algorithm is O(n) in general, I've said that.

Comment: @MisterSir: No it is not. As I keep saying, O-notation refers to how the complexity scales *as the input size is increased towards infinity*. You *cannot* say that it is O(1) if you restrict the input to a particular size, because that is not what O(1) means. (Even if you leave the implementation as it is, it will require twice as many iterations on a platform with 64-bit integers, than on one with 32-bit integers, so saying that this particular implementation is constant-time is not entirely accurate either.)

Comment: @Mike Now you're just being petty. You might as well just say "You can't say it's O(1) because it doesn't run at the same time with different processors!!"

Comment: @MisterSir: I think you may be misunderstanding me. You can't say it's O(1) because O-notation has a very specific meaning: it describes how the complexity of an algorithm scales with input size.  You can say that this particular implementation will always have the same running time on a given platform; you cannot say that it's O(1), because that specifically means that the algorithm's complexity remains bounded as you increase the input size, which is not the case. You may find the difference petty; others find well-defined, precise notation very useful for avoiding this kind of confusion.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: But there's no need for that because it is explicitly stated in this case that we are just talking about this specific implementation, and it's just comfortable to tag it O(1). While it may very well be a lacking definition, it suits our needs here, and easily helps describing this implementation. I see nothing wrong with that. So, yes, to me it seems petty.

Comment: @MisterSir: I don't find it comfortable to to say "the running time is bounded for all sizes of input" (which is what O(1) means, and which is quite wrong here), when I actually mean "the running time is constant for all input values of a particular size". I find it more comfortable to say what I mean (in English, in this case, since there isn't a widely accepted way of expressing that in mathematical notation), and not leave others guessing whether I'm using notation or words in an unusual way, or whether I'm simply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n is the input number, then NO_OF_BITS is O(log n) (think about it: to represent a binary number n, you need about log2(n) bits).

**EDIT**: Let me clarify, in the light of other responses and comments.

First, let `n` be the input number (`num`). It's important to clarify this because if we consider `n` to be `NO_OF_BITS` instead, we get a different answer!

The algorithm is *conceptually* `O(log n)`. We need to reverse the bits of `n`. There are `O(log n)` bits needed to represent the number `n`, and reversing the bits involves a constant amount of work for each bit; hence the complexity is `O(log n)`.

Now, in reality, built-in types in C cannot represent integers of arbitrary size. In particular, in this implementation uses `unsigned int` to represent the input, and this type is limited to a fixed number of bits (32 on most systems). Moreover, rather than just going through as many bits as necessary (from the lowest-order bit to the higher-order bit which is 1), this implementation chooses to go through all 32 bits. Since 32 is a constant, this implementation *technically* runs in `O(1)` time.

Nonetheless, the algorithm in conceptually `O(log n)`, in the sense that if the input was `2^5`, `5` iterations would be sufficient, if the input was `2^10`, `10` iterations would be sufficient, and if there were no limit on the range of numbers an `unsinged int` would represent and the input was `2^1000`, then `1000` iterations would be necessary.

Under no circumstances is this algorithm `O(n)` (unless we define `n` to be `NO_OF_BITS`, in which case it is).

Comment: @HighCommander4 ya thanks. what is the space complexity is it O(1) how??

Comment: Space complexity is O(1) because you only use a constant number of scalar variables (2 unsigned ints and 1 int) regardless of the size of the input. Suppose you used an array whose size was `num` (for whatever reason) - then the space complexity would be `O(n)`.

Comment: @High, I think you'll find time complexity is O(1) as well. `NO_OF_BITS` is not dependent on the input value since it uses `sizeof`, a constant, multiplied by another constant.

Comment: @HighCommander4 do u have any good materials r site to study the algorithm and their complexity calculation......

Comment: @HighCommander4: Complexity is measured in terms of the input size (i.e. `NO_OF_BITS` in this case), not in terms of the range of values the input can represent. This algorithm does a fixed amount of work for each input bit, so it is O(n).

Comment: @paxdiablo: say you have 32 records in a database and want to search through them.  Is a linear search O(1) or O(N)? Can inserting records change the big-O efficiency? Similarly, this is O(N) despite N being constant, just as Mike says.

Comment: @HighCommander4: even with your edit, this answer is wrong. The algorithm has to reverse the bits without knowing how many of the most-significant bits are 0s, so the conception about "if the input was 2^5, 5 iterations would be sufficient" is wrong - it presumes not only that the input is 2^5, but that it's known to be 2^5 in advance. That's NOT known, and discovering that requires more time and big-O complexity. "...unless we define n to be NO_OF_BITS" - which we must do because we don't know how many bits are actually in use, we must work off the potential number.

Comment: Further, in reversing the bits in an int you probably don't want ...0100 to become ...0001, instead to you want 0010... (i.e. LSB swapped with MSB, repeat moving inwards towards centre).  Not only is this generally more useful and intuitive, but it's the behaviour of the algorithm presented in the question so implicitly expected.  So, it's just as important to swap 0 bits as 1 bits, and the actual value of num is therefore less relevant (though there are algorithms that inspect num and work faster for certain distributions of values, such as frequently small values, or sparse bits).

Comment: @Tony: You make a good point about having to process the leading 0 bits too. But I still think it's O(log n) conceptually and only "constant time" because of the limitations of the data type we're working with. Suppose the input were an arbitrary-precision integer type - surely you agree that it would be O(log n) then?

Comment: @HighCommander4: in a purely mathematical sense I agree with you, but big O() being a computer science thing I think the logistical elements take priority.  Arbitrary-precision is a great example of where the representation reflects the mathematical value rather than restricts it, and in that case the complexity is indeed O(log(num)).  Think that explores all the perspectives and implications, and our actual understanding's common even if our idea of what people are most likely to expect "n" to be differs (num vs bits in type).  Cheers!

Comment: @HighCommander4,@Tony: When discussing complexity, "n" always means the size of the input (NO_OF_BITS in this case), not the number of values representable by it or anything else, and "O" always means an upper bound on complexity as "n" tends to infinity, regardless of any particular value of "n". If these terms didn't have well-defined meanings then it would be impossible to discuss complexity without getting into the kind of confusion and endless quibbling over definitions seen in this discussion. By these definitions, the algorithm in question cannot be anything other than O(n).

Answer (score 8):

Considering your above program, the complexity is `O(1)` because `8 * sizeof(unsigned int)` is a constant. Your program will always run in constant time.

However if `n` is bound to `NO_OF_BITS` and you make that number an algorithm parameter (which is not the case), then the complexity will be `O(n)`.

Note that with `n` bits the maximal value possible for `num` is `2^n`, and that in this case if you want to express the complexity as a function of the maximal value allowed for `num`, the complexity is `O(log₂(n))` or `O(log(N))`.

Comment: Good observation. Presumably the intention is not to go through all the bits, but only up to the highest-order bit, in which case it would be `O(log n)`.

Comment: Yes. The time complexity is O(1). It does the same number of loops _regardless_ of the input value.

Comment: @Benoit: No, that's a restriction on this particular implementation, not on the asymptotic complexity of implementations that can take arbitrary sized inputs (which is what O-notation describes).

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Yes, it is a restriction on that implementation. But still it answers the question about the complexity of the given code.

Comment: Another perspective that might make it click - `sizeof(unsigned int)` is not an absolute constant, but a compile-time constant: it can vary from one compilation environment to another.  Say some new hardware has 16384-bit ints... how will the performance scale?  Across all these environments, the algo is O(N).

Comment: @Benoit: Agreed, the given code has fixed running time. However, it's meaningless to describe it as `O(1)`, since `O` implies you're talking about the asymptotic complexity for large inputs, which isn't what you're talking about.

Comment: @Tony: Yes, but N is then bound to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Here a large input is `LONG_MAX`. But I agree that for a generic algorithm the algorithm has log(n) complexity.

Comment: @Benoit: no, if you're using O notation, then you're talking about asymptotic behaviour as input size tends to infinity. If you place an upper bound on input size, then you can't use O notation.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: This algorithm does not make sense if you must have input grow towards infinity. Suppose a generic algorithm, give it 2¹⁰⁰⁰⁰ as input. Reverse bits: you get one. Reverse again: how do you know how many bits you are about to reverse? You get 1.

Comment: @Benoit: A scalable implementation of the algorithm would need to specify how many bits there are in the input. I don't see how that affects the discussion in any way; O-notation refers to asymptotic complexity, and if you're talking about anything other than that, then you can't use O-notation.

Answer (score 4):

O-notation describes how the time or space requirements for an algorithm depend on the size of the input (denoted `n`), in the limit as `n` becomes very large. The input size is the number of bits required to represent the input, not the range of values that those bits can represent.

(Formally, describing an algorithm with running time `t(n)` as `O(f(n))` means that there is some size `N` and some constant `C` for which `t(n) <= C*f(n)` for all `n > N`).

This algorithm does a fixed amount of work for each input bit, so the time complexity is `O(n)`. It uses a working space, `reverse_num`, of the same size as the input (plus some asymptotically smaller variables), so the space complexity is also `O(n)`.

This particular implementation imposes a limit on the input size, and therefore a fixed upper bound on the time and space requirements. This does *not* mean that the algorithm is `O(1)`, as some answers say. O-notation describes the algorithm, not any particular implementation, and is meaningless if you place an upper bound on the input size.

Answer (score 1):

if n==num, complexity is constant O(1) as the loop always runs fixed number of times. The space complexity is also O(1) as it does not depend on the input

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear what n is. If n is `num` then of course your code is O(log n) as `NO_OF_BITS ~= log_2(n) * 8`.

Also, as you are dealing with fixed size values, the whole thing is O(1). Of course, if you are viewing this as a more general concept and are likely to extend it, then feel free to think of it as O(log n) in the more general context where you intend to extend it beyond fixed bit numbers.

Comment: ya thanks.s n is number. what is the space complexity is it O(1) how??

Comment: do u have any good materials r site to study the algorithm and their complexity calculation.....

Comment: @learnfromothers - The CLRS book is quite well known and is a good, very readable resource on algorithms and studying their complexity. See http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Second-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262032937 .

Comment: "n" always means the input size, which is `NO_OF_BITS` in this case. And if you are dealing with fixed-size input, then O-notation is meaningless, since it describes the asymptotic behaviour for very large inputs.